sram to shimano 11spd hub conversion dt swiss ratchet
I am attempting to convert this wheelset https://www.cannondale-parts.de/Cannondale-2020-HG-SL-45-KNOT-Wheelset from sram to shimano 11spd.
I have another ratchet freehub that I put on it, and it works as in the hub engages, but it doesn't seem to get flush with the body of the body of the rest of the hub. I can't seem to find what i need anywhere online. It looks like it is the older ratchet system, not the exp or sl. There also seems to be a mtb and road version of the dt swiss 240 hubs which I think what the inners are. Is it possible that cannondale made a proprietary freehub for this?
Many thanks in advance for the help!


It is not very likely that the freehub is unique to Cannondale. If the fit is close with the parts you have, can you determine by comparing the original freehub and the replacement, what about it is preventing a good fit. Use your vernier calipers etc. You should be able to make this work.

What brand/model of hub is on the wheel now?

Thanks for the response. Pretty sure it is a dt swiss ratchet freehub that is branded as a cannondale hollowgram. The replacement isn't going far enough down to create a proper seal between the freehub and the body.
